# Any other way to initialized int [] before use

Tags: java, arrays

Can anybody please tell why just way is going to work and not others.

Also if i want to make array size at run time, will i able to make it anyways.

```
public class RevesingSimpleArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        // 1 way will work
        int[] arr2 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        // 2 way not work
        // int[] arr2 = {};
        // 3 way not work
        // int[] arr2 = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            arr2[arr.length - (i + 1)] = arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(" leangth " + arr.length);

        System.out.println("Printing into reverse form --");
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(arr2[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to java and try to understanding few basics.
thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: JLS (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) will help you

Comment: int[] arr2 = new int[5]; maybe you are looking for this...

Comment: Thanks @andre its really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//  int[] arr2 = {}; // actually it gives `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
```

**You need to initialize the array before accessing it's elements through index**

```
//  int[] arr2 = null; // actually it gives `NullPointerException`
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**You need to initialize the array before accessing it's functions**

> Can anybody please tell why just way is going to work and not others.

Below are the few ways.

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[3];
int[] myIntArray = {1,2,3};
int[] myIntArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

> Also if i want to make array size at run time, will i able to make it
>   anyways.

yes something like this, get size and assign while initializing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ne = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter Number of Elements to create array with");
        ne = n.nextInt();
        int num[] = new int[ne];
    }
```

Comment: why the other ways are not working -
        int[] arr2 = {};
        
        int[] arr2 = null; , I have tried both, could you please explain.

Comment: @Avenger what is the issue, seems fine, no compilation issue.

Comment: In both the initialization i mentioned in comment have been done but I am having error null pointer but why it is the array of primitive datatype not the wrapper class type, so why i am having null pointer in this case.

Comment: your answer is right but i have asked few more things that i am not comfortable with. thanks for help.

Comment: @Avenger because acessing a null element or invoking something on it will cause a `NPE`. In your loop you are trying to acces the `arr.length` of a null object which would be the cause of your problem. And this doesn´t have anything to do with wrapper classes, since it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to make array at runtime:

```
int size = 5;
int[] array = new int[size];
```

Comment: Where does your `x` come from,